# C# Handling Null Values

Tags: c#, null, nullable

I have CustomerID   declared as

```
int? CustomerID=null;
```

I am checking null  values while  reading `DataReader`

```
Id = reader["CustomerId"] is DBNull ? null :Convert.ToInt32(reader["CustomerID"]);
```

It is  throwing

```
 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there 
  is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'int'
```

What is the problem with  the Conversion?

Comment: By "Id" are you referring to Nullable CustomerID declared at the top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to do it this way:

```
if(! reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("CustomerId"))
{
   Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CustomerID"]);
}
else
{
   Id = NULL;
}
```

You need to use the `.IsDBNull` method on the reader to determine ahead of time if a column is NULL - if it is, don't even read the value from the reader.

Comment: +1, better solution. If you don't like the multi-line approach, you might be able to add an extension method to the data reader class to allow single-line syntax in your code.

Comment: Is there an overload of IsDBNull that takes the column name? I can only find the int version on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx

Comment: @Justin Niessner: no, sorry - that would be my own extension method.... updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

Change your conditon to

```
  reader["CustomerId"] ==  DBNull.Value
```

Answer (score 2):

A ?: conditional expression cannot evaluate to two different types on the true and false condition. I think a cast `(int?)null` should work.

Comment: Yes, casting will solve the problem: Id = reader["CustomerId"] is DBNull ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(reader["CustomerID"]);

Comment: Well i don't like casting nulls. reader.IsDbNull is much cleaner.

Comment: I'm talking about "True" part of conditional expression. Not about checking reader if it is DBNull.

Comment: +1, this would address the specific error message, though it's not the best solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem (assuming that `Id` is declared properly) is that the conditional statement infers the result type from the true result. In your case, that type is `null`. It then will try to cast the second type to the same as the first...and there is no cast from `int` to `null`.

The solution is to cast the true expression to the desired type:

```
Id = reader["CustomerId"] == DBNull.Value ?
    (int?) null :
    Convert.ToInt32(reader["CustomerID"]);
```

Comment: +1 to reverse (uncommented) downvote. This is the correct answer to "What is the problem with this conversion."

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Id = reader["CustomerId"] is DBNull ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(reader["CustomerID"]);
```

the types of both parts of the ?: need to be explicit

Comment: +1 to reverse (uncommented) downvote. This is the correct answer to "What is the problem with this conversion."

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is your code is incorrectly evaluating and trying to do the Convert function.

Its readding `reader["CustomerId"] is DBNull` which it isn't its really a DBNull.Value so then it attempts to do `Convert.ToInt32("<null>")` and crashes.  You need to fix your if statement, and add a `(int ?)` cast.

It should be:

```
 Id = reader["CustomerId"] is DBNull.Value ? (int?) null :Convert.ToInt32(reader["CustomerID"]);
```

Comment: Tech, it would produce a new error, but his original error was because he was attempting to do Convert.ToInt32("<Null>");